# Affect to a "label" the value of the selected item of a combobox in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How to make the label receive the value of the selected item of `select`

My combobox:

```
<%= select("Cities", "destination", @city.map {|u| [u.name, u.code]}) %>
```

the `@city` variable has the result of an SQL query where i get all my `cities[]`
i want the value of the selected item to be written in a `"label" (<%= label("Cities", "name" %>`

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding on changing or on selecting you have to set label on UI.
To achieve this you have to use javascript,

set `id` for `select` tag suppose id is `country` and set some label id suppose 'country_label'

```
$("#country").change(function(){   

 var optionText = $("#country option:selected").text();  
 $("#country_label").text(optionText) // or val(optionText) check what is appropriate 

});
```

Or you have already selected combo box prior then you already know what is the value of city name you can directly add to `<%=f.label :city,elected city name %>`